# MS PowerBI - Show daily data based on hours from 7 am to next day 7 am

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have data for agents who are working on 3 shifts starts at 7 am and ends the next day 7am.

So if i want to show the number of cases made by agent especially night shift using the daily slices it will show data only from 23:00 until 00:00 not from 23:00 to 7:00 . so i need something which is doing this

For productivity of 1/1, If Agent A is night shift on 1/1/2022 then show data from 1/1/2022 @ 7am to 2/1 @ 7am

the raw data is like this

```
Date            Hour              Agent         Number of cases     Shift
1/1/2022        22:00             Mick          50                  Night
1/1/2022        23:00             Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        0:00              Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        1:00              Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        2:00              Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        3:00              Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        4:00              Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        5:00              Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        6:00              Mick          50                  Night
2/1/2022        7:00              Mick          50                  Night
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by creating an hourly hierarchy, its little bit time consuming to choose the hours one by one but it gave me the result i needed. thank you